# Align buttons in the middle of a container with ExtJS 4

Tags: extjs, extjs4, alignment

Question is simple.
I have a home screen where the north region has to display two textfields and one button to enable user to connect.

I have this code.

```
Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
    layout: 'anchor',
    id: 'homescreen', 
    items: [
        {    
            layout: 'border',
            border: false,
            height: 160,
            anchor: '100%',
            items: [
                {
                region: 'west',
                // some codes here
                },
                {
                xtype: 'container',
                width: '70%',
                region: 'east',
                layout: 
                    {
                    type: 'table',

                    columns: 1,
                    tdAttrs: 
                        { 
                        style: 'padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;',
                        align: 'middle',
                        },
                    defaults: 
                        {
                        width: 150,
                        textAlign: 'right'
                        },
                    },
                    items: [
                        {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        //fieldLabel: 'login',
                        labelWidth:50,
                        emptyText: 'Utilisateur',
                        margin: '18 0 0 0',

                        },
                        {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        //fieldLabel: 'mot de passe',
                        labelWidth:100,
                        emptyText: 'Mot de passe',

                        },
                        {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        html: 'Connexion',
                        scale: 'large',
                        },
                    ]
            }]

        },
```

As you can see, all the textfields and the button are aligned vertically on one column.
But problem is that they are displayed on the left side of the container. How can I display them on the right (without using css) ?
= 
 align them horizontally.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[VBox layout](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.VBox) would probably be more appropriated to your use case. It stacks component vertically and lets you control horizontal and vertical alignment of the resulting block.

Try the following layout, for example:

```
layout: {
    type: 'vbox'
    ,align: 'center' // or 'right'
    ,pack: 'center' // controls vertical align
    ,defaultMargins: 5
}
```

Comment: instead of the table layout  ?

Comment: brr leading commas :) but still... upvote ;) and yes instead of the table layout...

Comment: @SecularKid Yes, replace your own layout config with this, and play with it. It's one of my favorite layout, it fits many use cases. I'm pretty happy it's being integrated into CSS3 :)

Comment: @VDP It's [Saki](http://examples.extjs.eu/) that gave me that habit when I was a greenhorn JS dev... Maybe someone should notice him of the bad influence he is for the youth!

Comment: Hey thanks, it's working "more" but the pack seems to have no impact. align: right put all the component on the right of the container and right-aligned between themselves. pack : right, center, or left just changes nothing.

Comment: @rixo It's not bad. Just a matter of personal preference. As long as you stick to it (at least in the same files). SecularKid try 'start', 'center', 'end' as they are used in vbox and hbox (start means left or top). [docs](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Box-cfg-pack)

Comment: Possible values for pack are 'start', 'center, or 'end' (refer to the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.VBox-cfg-pack)). If you want to have different alignment for the fields and their container (e.g. align the fields to the right, but keep them aligned to the left between them), you'll have to nest them into another container. You should probably use [form layout](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Form) for the field container and [hbox](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.HBox) for its parent.

Comment: Saki is bada$$, leading commas had its day before automatic linting tools were so widely available :)